# Plot function issue - adding a line

Tags: r, plot, lm

My goal is to plot a line (red) using the plot function. This is what I have tried so far.

```
data("Nile")
plot(Nile)
fm0 <- lm(Nile ~ 1) ; summary(fm0)
y1 <- c(rep(1097.75, 20), rep(848.9722, 80))
 # Plot 
lines(fitted(fm0), col = "blue", lty = "dotted", lwd = 1)
lines(y1, time(Nile), col = "red",  lwd = 2)
```

The line in red color is not showing. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Expecting a plot like this

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to draw? Are you trying to draw the best fit line? (Which is really just the mean since you have an intercept-only model) I think you mean `abline(fm0, col = "blue", lty = "dotted", lwd = 1)` All the values of `fitted(fm0)` are identical, so there's no reason to draw a line for every one. Plus, if you don't pass x values as well, it assumes each value has an x value according to it's index (ie, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc) and that range is not in the range of times. You would need to get those values with `time(Nile)`.

Comment: @MrFlick, sorry for the confusion. I have updated my question with more specific example. I have generated 100 values, where 20 are 1097.75 and remaining 80 are 848.9722, and now trying to plot them as a red line, which is different from the `fitted(fm0)` which is not showing. Any reason why ?

Comment: What do you mean, you want to plot the 100 values as a red line? Maybe you should demonstrate what the final plot should look like, so we can better understand what you want. + For some reason, you're using cbind() where I think you just want c().

Comment: I think you want to flip your x and y values. Did you mean `lines(c(time(Nile)), y1, col = "red",  lwd = 2)`/ But this line isn't using any of the values estimated from the linear regression. It's still not very clear exactly what you are trying to draw.

Comment: @MrFlick, ZKA thanks both for the suggestion. I have updated my question with the expected plot. MrFlick, you are correct, I am not using any new values from the linear regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, so you're looking for what @MrFlick suggested above.

```
data("Nile")
plot(Nile)
fm0 <- mean(Nile)
y1 <- c(rep(1097.75, 20), rep(848.9722, 80))
abline(h = fm0, col = "blue", lty = "dotted", lwd = 1)
lines(c(time(Nile)), y1, col = "red",  lwd = 2)
```

which yields:
[image]